# NuGet pack and msbuild - how can pack reference assemblies in another location?

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I am using NuGet pack for the first time, using the AfterBuild target in the .csproj file.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <!-- package with NuGet -->
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(BaseDir)" Command="$(NuGetExePath) pack -Verbose -OutputDirectory $(OutDir) -Symbols -Prop Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
</Target>
```

This works fine when building the project itself with msbuild ("msbuild MyProj.csproj"). NuGet is able to find the compiled assemblies in projectdir/bin/Release or projectdir/bin/Debug.

But, this project is one of many in a solution and there is a build file dedicated to building the entire solution.  The directory tree is like this:

```
- project root
  - build
  - src
    - MyProj
      - MyProj.csproj
      - MyProj.nuspec
    - AnotherProj
      - AnotherProj.csproj
      - AnotherProj.nuspec
  - project.proj (msbuild file)
```

This msbuild file overrides the output path of the Visual Studio build.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CodeFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\src</CodeFolder>
  <CodeOutputFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\build\$(Configuration)</CodeOutputFolder>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="CleanSolution">
  <Message Text="============= Building Solution =============" />
  <Message Text="$(OutputPath)" />
  <Message Text="$(BuildTargets)" />
  <MsBuild Projects="$(CodeFolder)\$(SolutionName)" 
           Targets="$(BuildTargets)"
                 Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);RunCodeAnalysis=$(RunCodeAnalysis);OutDir=$(OutputPath);" />
</Target>
```

Now that the build redirects the assemblies to the build directory, when I run pack, NuGet can't find them.  How do I get NuGet to find the assemblies in the build directory?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Giving NuGet a TargetPath property for where to find the assembly works for this.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
  <!-- package with NuGet -->
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(BaseDir)" Command="$(NuGetExePath) pack -OutputDirectory $(OutDir) -Symbols -Prop Configuration=$(Configuration);TargetPath=$(OutDir)$(AssemblyName)$(TargetExt)" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to define files section in your *.nuspec files, set copy `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer` for them in VS properties. After that all you compiled files and nuspecs will be in `$(OutputPath)`. And then change AfterBuild to:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <NuspecPath>$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(OutputPath), "$(ProjectName).nuspec"))</NuspecPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- package with NuGet -->
  <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(BaseDir)" Command="$(NuGetExePath) pack $(NuspecPath) -Verbose -OutputDirectory $(OutDir) -Symbols -Prop Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: I did get it working like this, but it loses the conventions of using the .csproj for replacement tokens.  I've added an answer too, how do you think it compares?

Comment: Your solution looks better and absolutly right in this situation. I forgot about replacement tokens. But I didn't find documentation about TargetPath property except few discussions on codeplex. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: It's not documented well, I think I tracked it down with codeplex, some blog posts, the nuget targets file and source code.